# Authentication using a digital signiture

Tags: authentication, digital-signature

I'm new to the world of digital signatures and encryption and I'm trying to learn more.

I was wondering, how or if an authentication process (login or sign-in) can be performed using a digital signature or not.

I've thought of a scenario in which:

1. A user creates login credentials (username, password and PIN code).
   The password and PIN are used to create a private key.
2. The user tries to login via username & password. The password is compared to the one stored in the database and used to generate a key, which is also to be compared. If both match, then the user can login.

Does make any sense or should a public key be used?

Comment: I think you are confusing password hashing with digital certificates.  They are related but different.  The private key is normally as random as possible, but accessed using the password hash comparison.  I would suggest Wikipedia which may help you frame your question better.  Try "Digital Certificates" to start, but you may need to read a few articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client: *I wanna login!*

Server: *Okay. Here's a piece of data. Do something to it that only you could do!*

Client: *Okay. Here 's your data back. I've added a signature with my secret key.*

Server: *Lemme just check ... Okay, welcome in!*

This is a less than formal description of a challenge-and-response authentication protocol that uses signature. ;)